# Socket closed after calling bufferWriter.close(). Is it possible?

Tags: java, android, sockets, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I'm trying to communicate from my phone to my computer. I'm using socket! I would like to send a command from the app on my phone and receive a reply from the server.

So, I create a buffered writer and a buffered reader.

Unfortunatly, when I close the buffered writer, it seem like also the socket is closed ("java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed" error).

I don't understand what to do.

This is the code of the client.

```
private String sendCommand(String c){
    try {
        Socket ss = new Socket(host, port);
        //Send
        OutputStream sOut = ss.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sOut));
        bw.write(c);
        System.out.println("Comando: " + c + " spedito a: " + ss.getInetAddress());
        bw.close();
        //ss.close();

        //Read
        //Socket sr = new Socket(host, port);
        InputStream sIn = ss.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sIn));
        String reply = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("Risposta del server: " + reply);
        //br.close();
        ss.close();
        //return reply;
        return "stiamo lavorandoci";
    }
    catch (ConnectException connExc){
        Log.e(TAG, "Non riesco a connettermi al server.");
        Log.e(TAG, connExc.toString());
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        System.err.println("Problemi...");
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
    }
    return "Errore.";
}
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Well then dont close it. Why would you?

Comment: I tried also this way. But if I close the buffer after "System.out.println("Risposta del server: " + reply);" nothing happens. No error but the server doesn't receive nothing.

Comment: If I don't close the buffered writer, the server doesn't receive the command. This is the problem. But If I close it, also the socket is closed!!

Comment: Your client is reading lines but not writing lines. What does your server expect to receive? A line or some textbytes?

Comment: You could try to just flush() the buffer.

Comment: With flush() and read() instead of readLine(), I'm now able to receive something from server. Unfortunatly, the value is ever 115 also if I change the reply of server. Actually, things seem going better!! So thanks for help! The server is coded in python and the line that sends text to client is "socket.send("something".encode("UTF-8")". Let me know about this issue.

Comment: Add a "\n" at the end of every string your client sends.

Comment: All solved. Thanks very very much!!